# Creating new Object from existing object, how to make them independent - java

Tags: java, android, object, opencv

I don't understand why the following code is not working.
I am trying to create a new object using existing object elements, and then process the new object to change its elements. In the end both objects are changed. What am I doing wrong?

```
    contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    hierarchy = new Mat();

    //find contours of filtered image using openCV findContours function
    Imgproc.findContours(mFilteredFrameNoHoles, contours, hierarchy , Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    //Aproximate contours
    aproximatedContours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>(contours); 
    //aproximatedContours = (ArrayList<MatOfPoint>) contours.clone();
    //aproximatedContours.addAll(contours);

    aproximatedContours.doSomeOperations()
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `aproximatedContours` and `contours` have the same element references.

```
aproximatedContours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>(contours);
```

Simply creates a new list with the same elements in contours and if these elements are `mutated` the effects will be reflected in another list too.

Usually its a bad idea to toss around shared mutable objects like this, unless you really know the side effects. Following example demonstrates this behavior:

```
    class Foo{
        int val;
        Foo(int x){
            val = x;
        }
        void changeVal(int x){
            val = x;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Foo f = new Foo(5);
            List<Foo> first = new ArrayList<Foo>();
            first.add(f);

            List<Foo> second = new ArrayList<Foo>(first);

            System.out.println(first.get(0).val);//prints 5
            second.get(0).changeVal(9);
            System.out.println(first.get(0).val);//prints 9

        }

    }
```

Comment: But how can I create new object from old one and make them not related to each other? I want to process both objects separately...

Comment: You need a custom deep copying method. That said, don't rely on default `clone()` its an attrocity! It only does shallow copy. One should always be careful when a stateful object is shared.

Comment: Can you explain how exactly should I make such copy? I don't have any idea.